# Equality in an integral estimate

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u,v\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $1<p<\infty$ and $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Suppose, we have
$$\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u\nabla v\,dx=\left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p\,dx\right)^\frac{p-1}{p}\left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^p\,dx\right)^\frac{1}{p}
$$
Suppose the equality
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p\,dx=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^p\,dx
$$
holds. Then can we say that $u=v$ in $\Omega$?

I tried in the following way: Since the first given equality, which is the equality in Holder's inequality holds, and by the second given equality holds, we have $|\nabla u|=|\nabla v|$ in $\Omega$. Then I am unable to proceed.

Can someone please help to give an argument?

Comment: If $u = 1 + v$ you'll have $\nabla u = \nabla v$. Did you intend to have $u,v \in W_0^{1,p}$?

Comment: Thank you. No, I meant in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ without zero boundary value. Thank you again.

Comment: Even for $u,v\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, could you please show me a proof? Thanks. @ Umberto P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one step. Actually, you're first using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality pointwise:
$$
|\nabla u|^{p-2} \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \rangle \le |\nabla u|^{p-2} \cdot  |\nabla u| \cdot |\nabla v|,
$$
and then Holder's inequality:
$$
\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^{p-2} \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \rangle 
\le \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^{p-1} \cdot |\nabla v| 
\le \left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p \right)^\frac{p-1}{p}\left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}.
$$
If there's an equality, you can use equality conditions for both:

- Equality in Cauchy-Schwarz (for each point separately) tells you that for a.e. $x \in \Omega$ the vectors $\nabla u(x)$ and $\nabla v(x)$ are proportional (with a nonnegative ratio).
- Equality in Holder tells you that the functions $|\nabla u|$ and $|\nabla v|$ are proportional. Combined with the previous observation, this implies that the proportionality ratio of $\nabla u(x), \nabla v(x)$ is independent of $x$, so in fact the functions $\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$ are proportional.
- If additionally $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^p$, then this proportionality ratio has to equal $1$.

In consequence, $\nabla u = \nabla v$ a.e. In other words, $u$ and $v$ locally differ by a constant. Without some normalization (e.g., $u,v$ have zero trace on the boundary), nothing more can be said.

Comment: Thank you very much @Michał Miśkiewicz. But, still I have a doubt after the second step. Upto the second step we get $\nabla u=c\nabla v$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, if $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p\,dx=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^p\,dx$ holds, we obrain $|c|=1$. Hence $\nabla u=c\nabla v$, where $c=1$ or $-1$. How do you claim that the only possibility is $\nabla u=\nabla v$ that is $c$ has to be $1$? Kindly explain. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I forgot to mention that equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality also implies that the proportionality rate is nonnegative.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. From the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $|x.y|\leq |x||y|$, here we are using from one end, that is the fact that $x.y=|x||y|$, so $x=cy$ for some nonnegative $c$. So, we get $c=1$ in our case. Therefore, $\nabla u=\nabla v$. Thank you again @Michał Miśkiewicz

Comment: Yes. One minor subtlety is that in general equality in CS implies either $x=cy$ or $y=cx$ (as one of the vectors can be zero). This is why I was so pedantic about "proportionality".

Comment: Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

These assumptions imply $\nabla u=\nabla v$. The claim is trivially true if one of $\nabla u$ or $\nabla v$ is identically zero.

Using the assumptions and Hoelder inequality, we get
$$
0 \le\int_\Omega  |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla (v-u) \cdot \nabla (v-u)
\le \|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^p -2 \|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^{p-1}\|\nabla v\|_{L^p}^1
+\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^{p-2}\|\nabla v\|_{L^p}^2\\
= \|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^{p-2}(\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}-\|\nabla v\|_{L^p})^2=0.
$$
This implies $\nabla u = \nabla v$ for almost all $x$ for which $\nabla u(x)\ne0$.

Since we have equality in Hoelders inequality, the functions $|\nabla u|^p$ and $|\nabla v|^p$ are linearly independent. This implies $\nabla u(x)=0$ if and only if $\nabla v(x)=0$.

And $\nabla u = \nabla v$ follows. If $u,w\in W^{1,p}_0$ this implies $u=v$.

In general, $u=v$ does *not* follow, as the assumptions are fulfilled trivially if we set $v:=u+1$.